# Is it possible to change between two fontawesome icons on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I have an anchor tag with a font-awesome icon as follows

```
<a href="#" class="lock"><i class="icon-unlock"></i></a>
```

Is it possible to change to icon on hover to a different icon?

my CSS

```
.lock:hover{color:red}
```

Aside from the icon turning red I'd also like to change the icon to the following

```
<i class="icon-lock"></i>
```

Is this possible without the help of JavaScript? Or do I need Javascript/Jquery on hover for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using jquery or just plain javascript?

Comment: Hi @Avitus I've got Jquery going.

Comment: CSS cannot change page content. You need to use JavaScript.

Comment: @Diodeus, fontawesome icons are in CSS generated content. JavaScript is not necessary.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You could toggle which one's shown on hover:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<a href="#" class="lock">
    <i class="icon-unlock"></i>
    <i class="icon-lock"></i>
</a>
```

<sub>CSS:</sub>

```
.lock:hover .icon-unlock,
.lock .icon-lock {
    display: none;
}
.lock:hover .icon-lock {
    display: inline;
}
```

Or, you could change the `content` of the `icon-unlock` class:

```
.lock:hover .icon-unlock:before {
    content: "\f023";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Learned something new today ;)

Comment: Word of advice - do not use the first method. If you use it on say a table listing to change the delete icon on hover for example, you'll quickly notice a 'pop' effect when you scan over the icons. There should be no need to clutter your markup with all those extra icons when this can be done entirely in CSS with the second method.

Comment: the second method worked for me for my folder close and open, simple and clean. salute to zzzzBov!

Comment: @kapitan how exactly did you do it? I also want to have a closed envelope who turns to open when hover over:
CSS:
`.fa-envelope-open:before {content: "\f2b6";}`
HTML:
`<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-envelope-open fa-2x"></i></a>`
It just didn't work :/

Comment: this causes a flash though.

Answer (score 9):

In my templates I often use FontAwesome and I came up with this CSS trick

```css
* > .fa-hover-show,
*:hover > .fa-hover-hidden {
  display: none;
}
*:hover > .fa-hover-show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Add both icons to the HTML; the default icon should have the `fa-hover-hidden` class while the hover icon one should have `fa-hover-show`.

```html
<a href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-lock fa-hover-hidden"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-lock-open fa-hover-show"></i>
  <span class="fa-hover-hidden">Locked</span>
  <span class="fa-hover-show">Unlocked</span>
</a>
```

Given that the icon has a hover effect, it is likely that it is inside a button or link, in which case, a proper solution would be to also react to the change on :focus as well.

```css
* > .fa-hover-show,
*:hover > .fa-hover-hidden,
*:focus > .fa-hover-hidden {
  display: none;
}
*:focus > .fa-hover-show,
*:hover > .fa-hover-show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: and if i had a text that i want to change along with the icon, what should i do? Like <i class="icon-unlock"></i> Unlock <i class="icon-lock"></i> Lock

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks. Also, given that the icon has a hover effect, it is likely that it is inside a button or link, in which case, a proper solution would be to also react to the change on `:focus` as well.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using SCSS, you could simply do this. Much lightweight than any of the JS solutions and lighter on the DOM.

```
.icon-unlock:hover {
  @extend .icon-lock;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple way open css file of font awesome and change icon code on hover...

for example below is the code for lock icon

```
content: "\f023";
```

and here below is the code for unlock icon in css which you can put under :hover

```
.icon-unlock:before {
  content: "\f09c";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure CSS:

```
ul#menu i.fa-envelope:hover:before {content: "\f2b6";}
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery it would just be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.icon-unlock').hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('icon-lock');
            $(this).removeClass('icon-unlock'); 
        }, function () {
            $(this).addClass('icon-unlock');
            $(this).removeClass('icon-lock');
        });


    });
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeD_coder/SNR2T/) of this.

If you are using jquery ui then you can use .switchClass.

An example of this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".icon-unlock").switchClass("icon-unlock", "icon-lock");
});
```

The api on .switchClass() is located [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchClass/)