# Change Font Awesome icon on :hover

Tags: css, hover, icons, font-awesome

I hope this question was not already asked somewhere in this forum. I swear I searched it!

My goal is to change the "tag" icon when mouse is over it. Namely, I would like to let the "tags" icon appear replacing the old one.

I am quite sure there is an easy solution out there; probably using

```
.fa-tag:hover {
 background: url(something);
}
```

Here the page of my website with the .fa-tag icons : http://wordsinthebucket.com/about

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Change with what? Another icon?

Comment: Yes. 
As stated:
    Namely, I would like to let the "tags" icon appear replacing the old one.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 43):

I would have two icons but have only one visible at a time, toggling them based on `:hover` state. I feel this is more flexible then messing with `background`.

```css
.change-icon > .fa + .fa,
.change-icon:hover > .fa {
  display: none;
}
.change-icon:hover > .fa + .fa {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="change-icon">
  Tags
  <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-gear"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: great suggestion and very flexible.

Comment: For Font Awesome 6, I had to add a random class `faaa` to each icon and use my custom class in the CSS. For some reason, using the font-awesome-specific classes such as `fa-solid`  did not work.

Answer (score 11):

```
.fa-camera-retro:hover:before{
    content: "\f02d";
}
```

demo - http://www.bootply.com/oj2Io7btD7

you will need to change the `content` of `:before` pseudo element on hover

here is the list of complete fontawesome content codes

http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution looks easier to me. 
But unfortunately it is not working. 
Probably because my `.fa-tag`  icon is "inside" a `fa-ul`, a `fa-li` and an `a` tags?

Here the code:
`<ul class="fa-ul">
<li><a href="http://wordsinthebucket.com/author/dukemwacha"><i class="fa-li fa fa-tag fa-3x" style="color: #bc1313;"></i></a>`

Obviously I added your code to the CSS stylsheet.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is driving me mad. Literally. Not working for me. Here's my console: [i.imgur.com/7PX9nyH.png] And here my css modified: [i.imgur.com/elUwg3q.png]

Comment: Ok solved. As suggested, my CSS wasn't loading properly. Luckily my theme as its own custom CSS code editor which apparently is loaded before the style.css file. Adding the code there solved the issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

You can by adding CSS like:

```
.fa-tag:hover:before {
  content: "\f02c"
}
```

which changes the content in the `:before` pseudo element when hovering over the `.fa-tag`.

I'm quite sure it's not a good idea to overwrite the `.fa-tag` styling. At least scope it by a parent class, e.g. `.entry-content .fa-tag:hover:before` (although I would prefer a better class name like `author-tags`.

Comment: This is how it should be done. But better to use it like this `<i class="fa fa-tags change-icon"></i>`. And define `.fa.change-icon:hover { ... }`.

Comment: I like your approach the best frankly

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution looks easier to me. 
But unfortunately it is not working. 
Probably because my `.fa-tag`  icon is "inside" a `fa-ul`, a `fa-li` and an `a` tags?

Here the code:
`<ul class="fa-ul">
<li><a href="http://wordsinthebucket.com/author/dukemwacha"><i class="fa-li fa fa-tag fa-3x" style="color: #bc1313;"></i></a>`

Obviously I added your code to the CSS stylsheet.

Thank youa and @dfsq for your help.

Comment: See http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/emdKYX for a working example, and http://imgur.com/OOGL759 for how it looks in Chrome's DevTools. Perhaps your custom css isn't loaded properly?

Comment: This is driving me mad. Literally.

Not working for me. Here's my console:
[http://i.imgur.com/7PX9nyH.png]
And here my css modified:
[http://i.imgur.com/elUwg3q.png]

Comment: Ok solved. As suggested, my CSS wasn't loading properly. Luckily my  theme as its own custom CSS code editor which apparently is loaded before the style.css file. Adding the code there solved the issue. Thank you so much @ckuijjer and everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to overwrite fa-tag as you might need it somewhere else in a different scope. I would go like this:
http://antonakoglou.com/change-font-awesome-icon-content-hover/

which is actually the second part of this answer that I just discovered:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503006