# How to use plus/minus circle while expanding/closing for a dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, font-awesome

Im using font awesome CSS to display the plus circle on a dropdown, I want to change it to minus when the drop down is expanded and vice versa..

Any examples might help...thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change between two fontawesome icons on hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502835/is-it-possible-to-change-between-two-fontawesome-icons-on-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div to place in your dropdown, giving it the class of "more-icon", which will toggle to "less-icon" (this example requires a relative positioned parent)

```
.more-icon:after {
content: "+";
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
color: #373534;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 900;}


.less-icon:after {
content: "-";
width: 17px;
height: 4px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 15px;
background: #373534;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 900;}
```

Then, use some jquery to toggle the div between classes on your open and collapse for the dropdown:

```
$('.more-icon').toggleClass('less-icon');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a short interval to check if the dropdown is open or closed, then change the font awesome class.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukdesignservices/kxvnqee3/

```
var intvl = setInterval(function() {
    if ($("#dropdownMenu1").attr("aria-expanded") == "true") {
        $("#change-this").children(".fa-stack-1x").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus")  
    } else {
        $("#change-this").children(".fa-stack-1x").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus")     
    }
},10);
```

Dropdown code from: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: Thanks a lot, but im using angularJS instead of jQuery.

Comment: @Pradvaarcruz, Then you should tag it angularjs.