# Switching between Font-Awesome icons on hover

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to get my head around different solutions, yet none of them seem to work for my project.

The farthest I've got was with this;

```js
function onBackButtonHover() {
    const backButton = document.getElementById("page-controls").querySelector(".fas");

    $(backButton).removeClass();
    $(backButton).addClass("fas fa-arrow-left");

    $(backButton).mouseout(function(){
        console.log("Hello.");
    });
}
```

```css
page-controls .navbar-brand {
    background-color: #54aaff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 56px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}
#page-controls .navbar-brand:focus, #page-controls .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #fff;
    transform: scale(.85);
}
#page-controls .navbar-brand .fas {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 12px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//dfzlwjdb9r0y9.cloudfront.net/fa/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<a id="backButton intranet" class="navbar-brand" href="/dashboard" onmouseover="onBackButtonHover()">
    <i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i>
</a>
```

But the issue here is that I don't know how to restore the icon back to normal, once it has been changed, without using a static class. I would like to avoid using a static class, because the same script would run on pages with different icons, so classes will vary from page to page.

Another issue seems to be that the script is ran multiple times during one mouseover, as the `console.log` shows.

My goal would be to simply change the current icon to `fa-arrow-left` when the link is hovered, and switch it back to the original icon once it's done.

The solution should also cover mobile users, so it would have to register a touch-input as well - how should I approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change between two fontawesome icons on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502835/is-it-possible-to-change-between-two-fontawesome-icons-on-hover)

Comment: @MoshFeu Sadly not. That's the first article I stumbled across as well. Using the CSS to change the icon would work, but as I'm going to animate it with GSAP, that's not an option. I've also tried to implement some of the JS answers to that question on my own, but haven't got any results better than my example here.

Comment: I'm not sure what is GASP and if it can play nice with font awesome, but anyway, this answer should work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19503002/863110. If not, please fix your snippet so it will work and I'll show you.

Comment: @MoshFeu That would work if I would figure out, how to implement it in my case. As the icons are going to be different in each page. I can't simply set the `fa-user-lock` as a condition, when that's not going to work with other pages.

Comment: @MoshFeu Example updated, but it throws a weird error as well, which I am not sure why. My apologies, I'm a total dummy with JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right it's pretty simple

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  
  $('#backButton').on( "mouseover", function() {
    $('#backButton > i').removeClass('fa-user-lock').addClass('fa-arrow-left');
  });
  
  $('#backButton').on( "mouseout", function() {
    $('#backButton > i').removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass('fa-user-lock');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a id="backButton" class="navbar-brand" href="/dashboard">
    <i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i>
</a>
```

Now second part of your question - how to not hardcode classnames? Well, obviously you need to do something like this - read class of active element, remember it and use on mouseout... Something like this...
(I change `backButton` ID to class to show multiple icons example)

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  // Remember active class
  let tmpClass;
  
  // On mouse over
  $('.backButton').on( "mouseover", function() {
    // get current class
    tmpClass = $(this).children('i').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    // Swap
    $(this).children('i').removeClass(tmpClass[1]).addClass('fa-arrow-left');
  });
  
  // On mouse out
  $('.backButton').on( "mouseout", function() {
    $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-arrow-left').addClass(tmpClass[1]);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a class="navbar-brand backButton" href="/dashboard">
    <i class="fas fa-user-lock"></i>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand backButton" href="/dashboard">
    <i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand backButton" href="/dashboard">
    <i class="fas fa-bell-slash"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Working flawlessly, thank you!

For some reason however, the `fa-arrow-left` doesn't get removed with `removeClass`, but as it is not causing any visual problems at this point, I'll have to investigate it further. :)

Comment: Welcome! Btw I've double checked snippet with Dev. Tools and everything works properly with `fa-arrow-left` class - it is removed by `removeClass` method when `mouseout` triggers...

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, so that you can call same functions for different component with same functionality.

```js
function onBackButtonHover(e) {
    var i = $(e).find('i.fas')
  $(i).removeClass($(i).attr("default")).addClass($(i).attr("hover"))
}

function onBackButtonOut(e) {
    var i = $(e).find('i.fas')
  $(i).removeClass($(i).attr("hover")).addClass($(i).attr("default"))
}
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a id="backButton intranet" class="navbar-brand" href="/dashboard" onmouseover="onBackButtonHover(this)" onmouseout="onBackButtonOut(this)">
    <i class="fas fa-user-lock" default="fa-user-lock" hover="fa-arrow-left"></i>
</a>
```