# How to hover on the <li> element and toggle between the 2 icons[without JavaScript]

Tags: html, css, hover, font-awesome

I am trying to toggle between 2 icons whenever hover on the list, so that on hover on the link icon changes to another icon, and when we remove the hover it resets to the original icon.

```
<li>
 <span class="icons">
      <i class="ic1 far fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="ic2 fas fa-volume-up"></i>
 </span>
 <span>
     <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

This is my [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Neo1999/1ogb2trj/30/)

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Looks like your js fiddle link got lost. But maybe it's better to add the code directly to your question anyway since SO offers a similar functionality with its snippets.

Comment: You can look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502835/is-it-possible-to-change-between-two-fontawesome-icons-on-hover

Comment: Sure Thanks for the replies it was really helpful, it was my first question so I wasn't aware of some things, I'll make sure it won't happen again,

Comment: No problem :) We've all been there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even tho the Code isnt the cleanest, I guess that's what you are trying to achieve correct?

I didn't have the Font Awesome Icons thats why I inserted *a* and *b*

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}

li:hover .fa-check-circle {
 display: inline;
}

li:hover .fa-volume-up {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
 <li>
   <span class="icons">
      <i class="ic1 far hidden fa-check-circle">a</i>
      <i class="ic2 fas fa-volume-up">b</i>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd add `.fa-fw` to the icons to prevent the wobble effect.

```css
li:not(:hover) > .icons > .ic2 {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > .icons > .ic1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<li>
  <span class="icons">
      <i class="ic1 far fa-check-circle fa-fw"></i>
      <i class="ic2 fas fa-volume-up fa-fw"></i>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</a>
  </span>
</li>
```